# Is there a way to automatically fit an armature to a mesh?

Tags: mesh, armature, makehuman

I created a mesh in MakeHuman. For Unity I need an armature, but it needs to be fit inside the mesh. My mesh is in a weird position (not the T-pose) and I just cannot get all the fingers and joints to line up. Is there a way to make an armature automatically fit inside a mesh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MakeHuman is able to export a fully rigged model, just enable the 
the option in the export settings:

[image]

The complete process (including unity) is described here
[Unity Import Using Blender and Rigify](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/BlenderAndRigify.html)